# Manually running platform-conditional commands in a single test environment

Tags: python, tox

In one test environment, I'd like to perform one of two commands based on the platform I'm currently running. However, tox's documentation is a bit lacking in that regard. I found a [tutorial](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/platform.html) about multi-platform tests, and this [example](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#specifying-a-platform) about simple platform conditionals. Based on them I can create a single environment which either runs or doesn't based on the platform:

```
[testenv]
platform = win32
commands = python -c 'import sys; print(sys.platform)'
```

And a set of environments that run or don't based on the platform:

```
[tox]
envlist = py-{linux,mac,win}

[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    mac: darwin
    win: win32
commands =
    linux: python -c 'print("Linux")'
    mac: python -c 'print("Mac")'
    win: python -c 'print("Win")'
```

But where I fail is creating an environment that can be referenced with a single name, but that can still run platform-dependent commands. This runs everything succesfully, but with no output:

```
[tox]
envlist = whatever,platform-{linux,mac,win}

[testenv:whatever]
commands = python -c 'print("whatever")'

[testenv:platform]
platform =
    linux: linux
    mac: darwin
    win: win32
commands =
    linux: python -c 'print("Linux")'
    mac: python -c 'print("Mac")'
    win: python -c 'print("Win")'

; $ tox
; whatever: success, output "whatever"
; platform-linux: success, no output
; platform-mac: success, no output
; platform-win: success, no output
;
; $ tox -e platform
; platform: success, no output
```

All the platform options are run "successfully" with no output. Running `tox -e platform` instead of a bare `tox` produces no conditional environments and no output.

When the platform spec is moved to the parent `testenv`, it *almost* works!

```
[tox]
envlist = whatever,platform-{linux,mac,win}

[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    mac: darwin
    win: win32

[testenv:whatever]
commands = python -c 'print("whatever")'

[testenv:platform]
commands =
    linux: python -c 'print("Linux")'
    mac: python -c 'print("Mac")'
    win: python -c 'print("Win")'

; $ tox
; whatever: success, output "whatever"
; platform-linux: skipped
; platform-mac: skipped
; platform-win: success, no output
;
; $ tox -e platform
; platform: success, no output
;
; $ tox -e platform-win
; platform-win: success, no output
```

But the problem is that again no output is produced with `tox` or `-e platform` or `-e platform-win`.

So, how could I have a bare `tox` execute the right commands and still be able to run the single environment manually? Is it even possible with tox?

Comment: I don't think this is supported currently with tox (yeah, it's always all lowercase).

Comment: @Yeti Thanks for answering! In that case I might request it as a feature.